# Why having Issues when calling Model data into Controller to view?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm a beginner at Codigniter4. I'm just wondering "Am I missing something or my Code has some kind of problem?" Please check my code below, if anybody can help me to solve this issues I will be so glad full. I'm having the warning "Whoops! We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...".

Router.php

```
$routes->get('/country', 'CountryController::index');
```

CountryController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\CountryModel;
class CountryController extends BaseController{


public function index()
{
$country = new CountryModel();
    $data['country'] = $country->findAll();
    return view('country/index.php', $data);
}}
```

CountryModel.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
class CountryModel extends Model{


protected $table = 'country';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $allowedFields= [
    'countryName',
    'countryFlag'
];}
```

index.php

```
print_r($country);
```

Comment: *I'm having the warning "Whoops! We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...".* Inspect your error logs, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74746167/edit), and show us the error stack trace.

Comment: Or rename your ENV file to .ENV and change your environment to development so you can see errors in your browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time and advice. The problem is solved with your advice.